# Use buddypress function outside of plugin

Tags: plugins, functions

I have a question regarding Buddypress plugin.

It seems that I can use Buddypress function such as bp_core_signup_user() without any declaration on other plugins.

How is it possible?

I’m newbie to WordPress so please help me to understand the basic concept.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean “without any declaration on other plugins”? If BuddyPress is installed you can use it’s functions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm sorry I'm newbie to development. In case of using other function in files, I used class::function name, but in case of buddypress, I could use just function without any declaration and does not need include or require_once in my file. How could it possible? I wonder that reason :) Sincerely, Jen

Comment: Because that BuddyPress function isn’t a class method, and BuddyPress loads it when the plugin is loaded. What you can do depends on how each plugin works. You will need to check each Plugin’s documentation and learn some basic PHP concepts to understand why. Both those areas are off topic for this forum, but there are plenty of resources available.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I see. Thank you for your reply. It helps a lot. Have a good day!!